# Is it possible to cause email to my domain to be handled by gmail?

Tags: smtp, gmail

[This is a very narrow question, and I don't think it is covered in similar sounding questions]

I want to configure my server's DNS so that when someone sends email to me@myserver.com it is actually deliver it to myaccount@gmail.com

Note: My question is whether this is possible to do ONLY with DNS not with myserver.com's own sendmail.

I think the answer is "NO" it is not possible, because when I add an MX record to DNS the email that was delivered to gmail's SMPT server would be TO: me@myserver.com and it would not know that account.

(But I hasten to add that I am just vaguely starting to grok how this all works.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to sign up for [Gmail for Business](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/gmail.html) for this functionality, as you're quite correct, it needs to be supported by Gmail.

Addendum: As [others](https://serverfault.com/questions/219675/is-it-possible-to-cause-email-to-my-domain-to-be-handled-by-gmail/219685#219685) have pointed out you can do this [for free with Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/) if you have < 50 accounts. I wasn't aware this option existed.

Comment: not free anymore hope a free alternative will pop up soon!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps), which is free.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps is good. It's free ... There are some good free webmaster tools on google. google analytics and so on..